# unable to login into Dev Org

Tags: lightning, administration, login, trailhead, custom-domain

I was going through the Lightning Trailhead, which at one point wanted me to change my domain and promote it to the users. After this step I am unable to login into the same Dev org. Since it is a dev org, there is nobody else that can login and help me.

I tried reseting the password, and every time  I try to login it just redirects me to the same login page. I changed tha password already 5 time and still have no success.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you configure the login to require the domain as well? I.e. Did you check "Prevent login from https://login.salesforce.com"? If so, you will need to use your new domain login. You might find that an API based login tool can work around it if this is the case.

Comment: Yes Daniel is right. Also you can find the domain link to you org from your email (which you had used for domain change).

Comment: I tried to login through login.sf.com as well as the custom domain. After a couple of hours I was able to use the credentials on trailhead and developer.sf.com, but the dev org took almost a day to start working

Comment: Instead of going through the new changed domain link, Salesforce should allow to login using login.salesforce.com too. Try to login once from -  login.salesforce.com instead of logging in from trailhead and check whether you are able to login or not.

Comment: as already sid, .... it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem was that I forgot to deploy the custom domain to users after it was approved. If you go to My Domains settings, from there you need to finalize the process by deploying the my domain to users. After that the login.salesforce.com started working for me.